# MVC URLs return 404 in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2016

I have deployed my `ASP.Net MVC` app on server but it is not working. When I access it like `<server_ip>/controller/action` it says `404 - Not found` without further description. Then I added `index.html` file to the root in order to verify if I hosted the app properly and tried url as `<server_ip>/index.html` then it works. Do I need extra configuration to make my app work in MVC?

Comment: I would verify that your server has both ASP.NET Framework and MVC installed. 
In addition, your IIS setup needs to have the relevant modules installed. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configure-an-asp-net-website-on-iis

Comment: Did you assign `port number in IIS`? `<IP address>:port/<controller>/<action>`. Didn't you touch `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: @A.Nadjar I have assigned port 80 in IIS. There are changes in `RouteConfig.cs` but it is working in dev environement

Comment: I highly recommend you change the port to a free number; may be : `8085`. since the port number `80` may already been occupied to another process on the Server.

Comment: @A.Nadjar the problem was MVC packages was not installed on server. scgough's comment helped

Comment: Glad to be or assistance!

Comment: if your issue is resolved I request you to post the answer and mark as answer. this will help other people who face the same issue. @Imad